# ReactiveUI: Should I expect to receive a cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested using TakeUntil()

Tags: reactiveui

I have two simple Run/Cancel commands

```
Run = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(x => RunImpl());
Run.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw(ex.Message, ex));
Cancel = this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.Run.IsExecuting).ToCommand();
Run.TakeUntil(Cancel);
```

Should I expect a cancellation token signaled into my async method when Cancel is executed?

```
private async Task<bool> RunImpl(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
                //some stuffs
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                //next stuffs
                }
```

If it´s so, what I'm doing wrong? Because IsCancellationRequest never goes true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Run.TakeUntil(Cancel);
```

This has no effect, as it only creates a new observable, which will never be used.

```
    Run = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(x => RunImpl());
```

This will provide a default (never used) cancellationToken, hence will never cancel.

I believe the correct way is:

```
    Run = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => Observable.StartAsync(RunImpl).TakeUntil(Cancel));
    Cancel = this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.Run.IsExecuting).ToCommand();
```

This way, the observable returned by `TakeUntil` will be suscribed by the command when executing, and `TakeUntil` will take care of canceling whenever the `Cancel` command runs.

Comment: You are right!, thank you very much Gluck.
I'm still figuring out how to use Rx properly